# Getting an error when creating a new directory and moving files

Tags: python, shutil

I have a script that, after creating a bunch of files, will create a new directory and then move those files into that new directory. It was working at first but all of a sudden I am getting an error and I don't know why it is coming up.
EDIT: I added my earlier code (all in same module) for those wondering.

My code:

```
import os
import shutil
mydir = os.getcwd()

def edit_and_rename_files():
    f = filelist() # an earlier script that just makes a list of files I care about
    for item in f:
        with open(item, "r+") as id_file:
            for line in id_file:
               does something
              return my_dict # just a dict with ids I want to rename

        with open(item, "r+") as infile:
            content = infile.readlines()
            new_content = []
            for line in content: # going to copy and rewrite some lines
                new_line = line
                for original_id, new_id in my_dict.items():
                    new_line = new_line.replace(original_id, new_id + "\n")
                new_content.append(new_line)

       with open(item+"_renamed.fa", "w") as outfile:
           for line in new_content:
               outfile.write(line)

edit_and_rename_files()                 


def move_files():
    renamed_dir = mydir + "\\renamed"
    if not os.path.exists(renamed_dir):
        os.mkdir(renamed_dir)
    else:
        print "This directory already exists. Will move the files into this directory anyways."

   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(mydir):
        for fname in files:
            if fname.endswith("_renamed.fa"):
                shutil.move(fname, renamed_dir)

move_files()
```

This script executes and the files are created and actually move fine (no mistakes when I open the files), but I still get an error which bugs me to see.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename_concatenated_file_ALL.py", line 59, in <module>
    move_files()
  File "rename_concatenated_file_ALL.py", line 58, in move_files
   shutil.move(fname, renamed_dir)
File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 292, in move
   raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst
shutil.Error: Destination path 'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\RenamingWork\atp_main\renamed\atp_main_renamed.fa' already exists
```

Comment: why not use the same test in the file creation than in the folder creation ? with `os.path.exists`

Comment: `shutil.move()` tries to overwrite the existing file, but sometimes it cannot. Common reasons include: the file is open and can't be deleted, or the user does not have access to delete the file. Can you verify none of those are true in your case?

Comment: You mean why not incorporate the move_files function with the earlier function that created the files? I did try that but I was getting weird errors and I am only a beginner...it was just easier for me to break my objectives down into individual functions. But my move_files() function is in the same module as my create_files() function. I have the create_files() execute, then within the same script I then call move_files() at the very end.

Comment: I used with open() to avoid errors of files not being closed (that is what I learned...) and I have access to delete these files and edit them.

Comment: if it works and you don't want to see the error, just `try/except` the command and `pass` in the `except` block.

Comment: @DNAngel - I don't understand. Are you saying that your files are still kept open in your script when your `move_files()` function is called?

Comment: I just added the file.close() method to any open files, ran the script again and the same thing still happens. The files are not left open.

Comment: @JacobIRR - I'm sorry, but that is bad advice. It doesn't "work" if it is throwing an exception. Based on what the stack trace shows, it is not working as intended.

Comment: @DNAngel - Post your code where your are calling `move_files()`

Comment: I read "This script executes and the files are created and actually move fine (no mistakes when I open the files)" as meaning it was working to OP's expectations

Comment: I did post my code, did you want to see the entire code before that where I rename some files? I ran that part individually and it works fine with no errors or anything. I just wanted to add this move_files bit so I could organize the files better

Comment: @JacobIRR - Even so, that is still bad advice. If an exception is thrown, its for a reason and should be fixed - not hidden.

Comment: It's weird, it is working - the files do move and the new folder is created. So I am so confused as to why it works WHILE throwing out this error message.

Comment: @DNAngel - The code you posted doesn't do anything unless you call `move_files()`. Where in your other code do you call it? Need to see it in context

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I forgot to use the 4 spaces at the end where I had move_files().

Comment: So I ran the first part of my script where I just created all the new files. I then ran the script with both functions to see what would happen, and it actually moved all the previously created files into the new directory (no duplicated files anywhere) - but the error still comes up. It seems to do exactly what I need but I am worried this error is doing something weird that I won't know till later.

Comment: Does a file with the same name exist in the directory you are moving it to prior to calling `move_files()`?

Comment: Hmm not in the current directory. I do however use the "rename" folder name in other directories where I am not running this script. The idea is that I am working with different genes (each it's own directory) where I want to have a rename, log, seq folder for each one. Maybe os.walk detects all of those even if they are not in my current directory?


Edit: I tested that out by renaming other "renamed" folders and then running the script. Same thing happens. Directory is created, files are moved, but the error shows up.

Comment: try using the full path to the file when using shututil.move.
    shutil.move(os.path.join(root,fname), os.path.join(renamed_dir,fname))
that solved issues for me getting that error